# Make KDE's task switcher respect Alt+Shift+Tab - with HE/EN keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, alt-tab, task-switching

I'm using KDE 4.14. on Fedora 20 (sorry, it's not my choice). 
Now, when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get the task switcher. Keeping the <kbd>Alt</kbd> down, I can select a task using <kbd>Tab</kbd> keypresses to scroll right. But coming from Windows, I'm used to beingl able to use both  <kbd>Tab</kbd> and  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in this state to scroll left and right - and my KDE doesn't seem to allow this: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> scrolls to the right as well.

I suspect this might have something to do with my keyboard layout:

I'm also using a dual-language keyboard layout:

```
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete+caps(shift)+numpad(microsoft)"        };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+il:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"       };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc101)"     };
};
```

which causes keyboard behavior to act up a bit in other situations as well.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked the KDE hot-key bindings? Last time I used KDE, it had hot-key settings in the control panel (or whatever it is being called in KDE).

Comment: @zagrimsan: It tells me Alt+Shift+BackTab should work, whatever that means. I can't change it from the default, it tells me that "That key is not supported by Qt".

Answer (score 1):

On my system you need one finger more: use 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to scroll left in the list of tasks.

It works even with 2 fingers only:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> , do not release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to go left or right.

**EDIT**
After your edit I find [this link](http://www.vinc17.org/unix/xkb.en.html). 
What it follow it's just an hint.
You can try to backup your *XKB* customization file and to do some experiments.

With the command   `setxkbmap -types local -print` on the system on which I am now, I obtain something similar to

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "local" };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+il:2+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc101)"     };
};
```

You can start with this one as your new custom file.
If it works you can modify what you need until you will find the option in conflict.

Comment: See edit. Shift+Tab doesn't work for me with Alt held down after Alt+Shift. However, +1 for the arros suggestion, that's something I guess.

Comment: @einpoklum. I added a link and a working configuration `xkb_keymap`. Good hunting.

Comment: I'm not going to give up Alt-Shift toggling to avoid the problem - I need that even more...

Comment: @einpoklum So have you verified that Alt-Shift toggle triggers this (removing that would solve the issue)?

Comment: @einpoklum The use of shift to _logic negate_ a command is a general behaviour of _KDE_ (e.g. Ctrl-Z and Shift-Ctrl-Z for Un-Do Re-Do)...  I remember that to switch between 2 language layout I mapped the command with a different combination (something like Shift-CapsLock...) instead of Alt-Shift. If this is the problem I think you can find a lot of other not harmful combinations...

Answer (score 1):

I think <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> doesn't work because it set to change layout. So while <kbd>alt</kbd> is pressed pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> will change the layout. You'd use <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> but if <kbd>alt</kbd> already pressed this is not the fix.
So maybe <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and then <kbd>RightShift</kbd> / <kbd>LeftShift</kbd> while  <kbd>alt</kbd> is pressing the only way we can use.

Btw, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> had an issue too if you use "selecting by the word" you'll get changing layout instead of a "selecting by the word".

If some have an fix for this i'll be great!

Comment: Change what layout?